# ng-show with own ng-controller alerting on load and multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Why is my alert being called on page load and being called twice?  Is that normal behavior?

I also have a ng-click on some images in another div/controller and it is calling the alert. ????? Added below.

I have a html markup like below.

```
 <div class="item-blue" ng-controller="ItemController as item">
 <div class="col" ng-show="item.checkItem('foo')">
```

Then in my controller is the below.

```
 app.controller('ItemController', function() {
     this.checkItem = function(bar) {
     alert(bar);
     };
 });
```

Weird!!!!

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBjJyw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because AngularJS sets up a "watch" on the expression that you use for `ng-show`. It then regularly re-evaluates that expression (during something called the *digest cycle*) to see if the value has changed. Since your expression involves calling a function, that function will get called every time the expression gets evaluated.

This *digest cycle* happens **extremely often**, and you can't always control when it happens. As a result, only ever call functions in expressions used for things like `ng-if`, `ng-show`, `ng-class`, etc if they just return a value (as opposed to doing something like showing an alert, changing state, etc).

Here are just some of the situations which trigger the digest (there are many more):

- A HTTP request returns
- You call `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` explicitly
- Using `$timeout` or `$interval`
- You click the mouse, type a key or move the mouse (if directives that listen to those events are used)

As you can hopefully see, that is a lot of causes for it, so you don't want to do more work in it than required, and all the expressions it evaluates should only ever return values.

Comment: Thanks for dropping knowledge Greg.  I am using this to return a value to then hide/show (true or false).  Is that acceptable usage?

Comment: Absolutely. The only time you should do any more than read values and return values in expressions is for event-based things like `ng-click`, `ng-keypress`, etc. They only get run when the event occurs. Most other things will get continually run, so should be as _pure_ (devoid of side effects) as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It's a normal behavior in angular js as it seems to keep happening no matter the approach you take because of the ng-show, angular tries to check the condition (which in this case calls a method "checkItem()" which pops up an alert box) so i don't think this is as a result of any code malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

Does `ItemController` appear on the page more than once? That could explain the behavior you are experiencing.

Comment: Nope.  Saw that on another post on here and double checked.  I'm just trying to figure out if that is normal behavior in Angular.

Comment: What happens if you use `ng-controller="ItemController"` in the first div, and `ng-show="checkItem('foo')"`?

`checkItem` is a function bound to the `$scope`, yes?